# Different Colorscale per State on Map of U.S

Tags: geopandas

Currently if I plot a map of the U.S., the color scale applies to all states.  So, for example, California may have the only dark red county and Alabama may have the only dark blue county.  What I want is for each state to have the full scale.  The data I am plotting is already state-specific so I just need the min and max to be state-specific if that makes any sense?  All I could think of is to normalize it in the data by creating a new metric with a range from -1 to 1 relative to the the state's min and max.  Is that the best way to do it or is there some more elegant or supported way to do this?

Comment: Are you going to add 50 colorbars to explain the mapping for each state?

Comment: Good question.  No I don't need color bars.  They will have the data behind the charts.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using groupby to establish the min and max for each state and then just used this formula...

normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

...from [here](http://normalized%20=%20(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))

and used that for the plot variable.